# Add whitelist IP to a restricted country

Tags: facebook, ip, country

We have an application what is only going to be available in the UK -  so using the Developers console, under 'Settings' - 'Advanced' I have put United Kingdom in the 'Country restrictions' settings to block out all other countries.

However, we have a call center in Ireland that I need to provide access to the application -  I have tried adding their IP address to the 'Server IP Whitelist' but they are not able to see the application.

Am I able to have Ireland blocked as a country -  but have specific IP's opened?

Thanks

Comment: Can you tell us how you are blocking? To the `Server IP Whilelist` doesn't tell us anything. You will need to provide us with the OS, the http server, the program you are using for blocking and the contents of your white and black lists. Your current question is impossible to answer. Also this probably should be on serverfault.

Comment: Hi;I am blocking solely using the Facebook developer console.  Under advanced settings there is a Server IP whitelist setting.

Comment: You need to put that kind of information in your question and add a facebook tag.

Comment: _“I have tried adding their IP address to the 'Server IP Whitelist' but they are not able to see the application.”_ – of course not, because they are the __client__ and not the _server_. The server IP whitelist is for servers your app is allowed to send requests from to the API.

Comment: Thanks -  that makes sense -  please excuse my ignorance :-)